# create a custom js library, analyzing a personal js file

Tags: javascript, compression, canvg

I would like to know if there is an automated way to analyze my javascript code in search of functions taken from a js library (like jquery and canvg ) and automatically create a minimal version of the library that contains only the features used on my page.

Comment: there are tools on the web like snappy snippet which allow you to select an object and extract all markup, css and scripts used to be able to reproduce the object elsewhere (e.g. jsfiddle) but to do this for an entire site, I would not be certain. Chances are if you strip out a load of functions which were not called, in a different browser/OS etc those functions not called initially and therefore removed may be needed and the site would not work.

Comment: jQuery uses too many internal closure to be able to reverse-engineer the depends programatically. you can use a variety of trick to find other shallower depends though.  http://danml.com/packager/ can help throw out redundant code and prevent accidental implicit globals, among other things, while packaging all your functions into a module.